# How do I resolve this error message? Azure DevOPs TF401232:Work item does not exist, or you do not have permissions to read it

Tags: permissions, devops

Azure DevOPs TF401232:Work item does not exist, or you do not have permissions to read it

Answer (score -1):

Open project setting -> Project configuration -> Areas -> select area path( 01 - Template ) -> click “…” -> security -> search for your account and then check the permission-View work items in this node and ensure it set to allow.

ALSO, make sure you are not part of the User Group that has an access level set to deny for view work items for respective node.

Comment: what if the csv file is workitems from a different organization project?  is it possible to first export to csv file and then import in another project?

Comment: @serup just remove the id column from csv file

Comment: @dymtro, able to import when uploaded without ID, but the state field it shows error

Comment: @priya I am facing the same problem, would you be able to resolve it?